# Fragment from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have two fragment called WiFiChatFragment and another is AboutUsFrag
so, i want to call AboutUsFrag from WiFiChatFragment but from overflow menu item i have already implemented but it gives error at replace method
here is my    WiFiChatFragment code

```
public class WiFiChatFragment extends Fragment {
private View view;
private ChatManager chatManager;
private TextView chatLine;
private ListView listView;
public Animation hyperspaceJump;
public AboutUsFrag fragment=null;



public static final String TAG = "Settings";

ChatMessageAdapter adapter = null;
private List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
Context context;
private FragmentTransaction ft;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
    chatLine = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtChatLine);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    hyperspaceJump = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.animation_leave);
    chatLine.startAnimation(hyperspaceJump);



    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    adapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.id.text1,
            items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    view.findViewById(R.id.btn_send).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (chatManager != null) {
                        chatManager.write(chatLine.getText().toString()
                                .getBytes());
                        pushMessage("Me: " + chatLine.getText().toString());
                        chatLine.setText("");
                        //chatLine.clearFocus();

                    }
                }
            });


    return view;



}
public interface MessageTarget {
    public Handler getHandler();
}
public void setChatManager(ChatManager obj) {
    chatManager = obj;
}
public void pushMessage(String readMessage) {
    adapter.add(readMessage);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
/**
 * ArrayAdapter to manage chat messages.
 */
public class ChatMessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    List<String> messages = null;
    public ChatMessageAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                              List<String> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
        }
        String message = items.get(position);

        if (message != null && !message.isEmpty()) {
            TextView nameText = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            if (nameText != null) {
                nameText.setText(message);
                if (message.startsWith("Me: ")) {
                    nameText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.out_message_bg );
                    nameText.setTextAppearance(getActivity(),
                            R.style.normalText);
                } else {
                    nameText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.in_message_bg );
                    nameText.setTextAppearance(getActivity(),
                            R.style.boldText);
                }
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);


}

public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment ) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.about_frag, someFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // do s.th.
            return true;

        case R.id.clean:
            adapter.clear();
            return true;

        case R.id.about_us:
            fragment = new AboutUsFrag();
            replaceFragment(fragment);

            return true;
        case R.id.rating:
            return true;



        default:


            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}




}
```

and another class called AboutUsFrag

```
public class AboutUsFrag extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us, container, false);
    }

}
```

How can I implement this ?

Comment: Please show me the error in LogCat.

Comment: it give error on replace method it not accept fragment

Comment: Please post the error straight from your logcat. eg. what is the error? what is logcat telling you?

Answer (score 0):

Check import section.
You need to import

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

I hope it work.

Comment: after commenting there is no effect.

Comment: error after running  Error:(199, 17) error: method replaceFragment in class WiFiChatFragment cannot be applied to given types;
required: Fragment
found: AboutUsFrag
reason: actual argument AboutUsFrag cannot be converted to Fragment by method invocation conversion

Answer (score 0):

Lets just try to

```
 import android.app.Fragment;
```

and replace fragment like this way

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,frgment,"fragment_id").commit();
```

Comment: again it gives error like: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.codes.asd.appshare, PID: 10043
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0055 (com.codes.asd.appshare:id/about_frag) for fragment AboutUsFrag{41cb6088 #1 id=0x7f0d0055}

Comment: can you tell me here fragment _id ,there already one id is present R.id.frame_container so the which id require there

Comment: just an id assign to know which fragment is being replaced , which can later you use by its id (you can set anything here)

Comment: after applying getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,frgment,"fragment_id").commit() i got new error as java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.app.FragmentManagerImpl android.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference

Comment: Please call this in the method that you created "public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment )"    and pass someframent in it as getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, someFragment,"fragment_id").commit();